# how to run system command in perl script with Cygwin

Tags: perl, unix, cygwin, spawn

I'm trying to implement a perl script in Cygwin. The script makes a few different calls within. For example,

```
system "C:\\users\\program.exe";
```

or

```
exec("C:\\users\\program.exe");
```

When I try to run it in cygwin, it gives me the error:

```
sh: C:cygwin64cygdriveprogram.exe: command not found
```

I know this is a dumb question, but how do I make it find program.exe?? If I look through the directory in the cygwin terminal then program.exe is clearly there...

Once I have it find the program, I would like to spawn the new process in a new cygwin terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Unix file separators and the `/cygdrive/c/` virtual drive:

```
system "/cygdrive/c/users/program.exe";
```

or

```
exec("/cygdrive/c/users/program.exe")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 exec("C:\\users\\program.exe");
```

executes the bourne shell command

```
 C:\users\program.exe
```

which is a weird way of writing

```
 C:usersprogram.exe
```

Executing the following shell command might work:

```
 C:\\users\\program.exe           # exec("C:\\\\users\\\\program.exe");
```

But the correct path is

```
 /cygdrive/c/users/program.exe    # exec("/cygdrive/c/users/program.exe")
```

Answer (score 2):

TMTOWTDI:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @cmd = ("/c", "echo", "hi" );

system('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe',       @cmd) == 0 or die;
system('C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe',          @cmd) == 0 or die;
system('/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe', @cmd) == 0 or die;

chomp(my $cmd = `cygpath 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe'`);
system($cmd, @cmd) == 0 or die;
```